# emberjs: is there a way to create a catch all route?

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way to create a route with dynamic segments that go to an arbitrary depth?

In other words is there a way to setup a route with a catch all? Something like this

```
Em.Route.extend({
  route: "/:segment/*"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this has been implemented, and just pushed into master: see https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1465

I've not tried yet, so I will be glad if you can give some feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can now create a route like this via Route Globbing:

```
@resource 'files', path: '/*filepath'
```

And the `params` parameter sent to the `model` callback will include a param called `filepath`

It also works going the other way in a `link-to` helper where you can do something like

```
= link-to 'files' mypath
```