# Ember.js: a way to do a real catch all route?

Tags: ember.js, routes, ember-router, catch-all

I know something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12025459/emberjs-is-there-a-way-to-create-a-catch-all-route) can be done but what I'm asking for is an `else` route that will match any URL (or state) that wasn't previously defined.

This could be handy to catch if a user is trying to access an invalid state or URL.

However, is okey if there is another way to do this :D

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is taken from the answer to another question, [so upvote that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15098585/980459):

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('catchAll', { path: '*:' });
});

App.CatchAllRoute = Ember.Route.extend({ 
    redirect: function() {
        this.transitionTo('index'); 
    }
});
```